# Makefile: /usr/lib/libjpeg.so or -ljpeg

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am working on an old library with an old Makefile. This file specifies the jpeg library to link as "/usr/lib/libjpeg.so". I would like to replace that with "-ljpeg".

My question is: if there is both libjpeg.a and libjpeg.so installed on the PC, what will "-ljpeg" select for linking? What do I have to do to specify the selection to choose in the Makefile?

Will "-ljpeg" work in both 32bit and 64bit mode while I guess "/usr/lib/libjpeg.so" will only work for 32bit?

Comment: the last sentence doesn't quite make sense… "Will "-ljpeg" work in both 32bit and 64bit mode while I guess "/usr/lib/libjpeg.so" will only work for 32bit?" – why do you think that would be the case?

Comment: Unless there is something like `-Bstatic`, most systems will favor a .so over a .a in the same directory. Btw, why do you believe that /usr/lib is specifically for 32 bits? That might be true on one specific distribution for one specific architecture... There could also be subtleties if libjpeg.so is missing a soname, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: My SUSE Linux distro keeps the 64bit versions of the libraries in /usr/lib64 so I thought this is pretty much standard. And I thought "-ljpeg" "knows" this somehow if I compile on a 64bit distro.

Comment: I did ask Google to find "-Bstatic" but got no result. Is this parameter documented somewhere?

Comment: [If you Google for a term with a dash in front it will *negate* that term in your search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en).  [Search for "Bstatic" instead.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523258)

Comment: Thank you ;-) Now I found it - it seems to be very useful parameter. Plus I read there that by default the linker will link against a shared library if available!